# How to map a forEach into an accordion in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foreach, accordion

Currently I am trying to map 2 objects using a forEach method in angularJS and display them in an accordion. I'm not really getting the result that i want...it's not really filtering or spitting out the right data that i want in the html.

here is what i have so far...

HTML:

```
<accordion ng-repeat="fee in fees">
  <accordion-group ng-if="fee.feeBag.length">
    <accordion-heading>
      {{fee.headingName}}
    </accordion-heading>
      <div class="feecode-height" ng-repeat="feeParameter in fee.feeBag">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-1">{{feeParameter.name}}</div>
          <div class="col-xs-4">{{feeParameter.text}}</div>
          <div class="col-xs-2" >{{feeParameter.amount}}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

Controller:

```
angular.forEach($scope.fees, function(value, key) {
  angular.forEach(value.feeBag, function(value2, key2) {
    if (value.feeBag[key2].name === $scope.otherFees.name) {
      value.feeBag[key2].text =  $scope.otherFees.text;
      value.feeBag[key2].amount = $scope.otherFees.amount;

      return value.feeBag[key2];            
    } else {
      // remove the ones that dont belong 
      // value.feeBag.splice(key, 1);
    }

  });
});
```

JSON values:

```
$scope.otherFees = [{'name': 1, 'text': 'ok', 'amount': 2}, {'name': 2, 'text': 'hello', 'amount': 3}, {'name': 3, 'text': 'cool', 'amount': 3}]

$scope.fees = [
  { 
    'headingName': 'firstHeader',
    'feeBag': [
      {'name': 1}
    ]
  }, 
  {
    'headingName': 'secondHeader',    
    'feeBag': [
      {'name': 2}
    ]
  },
  {
    'headingName': 'thirdHeader',    
    'feeBag': [
      {'name': 3}
    ]
  }
]
```

I'm just kind of stuck on where i should go next....it seems like i set it up right to group the values by heading name and have the individual sets display in the rows.

appreciate all the help :D

Comment: Try changing the `ng-if="fee.feeBag.length"` to `ng-if="fee.feeBag.length > 0"`

Comment: The header works fine...it's the rest of the stuff that doesn't work well

Comment: Are you trying to use the bootstrap accordions or something else? The bootstrap ones are converted to accordions using div tags with panel classes.

Comment: The accordions itself works fine....I think it's the foreach filtering that's not working correctly

Comment: I haven't used Angular too much and I had never used the custom Accordion tag before today. I am just trying to help. I just put your code into a JSFiddle, let's see if we can fix this. Modify it to your code if I have made any mistake: https://jsfiddle.net/luthrayatin/avuL06v3/1/

Comment: I just realized, you need to loop through otherFees before comparing

Comment: yea thats where i'm having the issue....not really sure how to loop through otherFees while still being associated with fees

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148000/discussion-between-yatin-and-jeremy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another loop inside to check for each value of `$scope.otherFees` items:

```
angular.forEach($scope.fees, function(value, key) {
    angular.forEach(value.feeBag, function(value2, key2) {
        angular.forEach($scope.otherFees, function(value3, key3){
        if (value.feeBag[key2].name === value3.name) {
          value.feeBag[key2].text =  value3.text;
          value.feeBag[key2].amount = value3.amount;

          return value.feeBag[key2];            
        } else {
          // remove the ones that dont belong 
          // value.feeBag.splice(key, 1);
        }
      })
    });
  });
```

Have a look at the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/luthrayatin/avuL06v3/2/). I have updated it. I hope that's what you were looking for.